# Parse string "20151112 221433" (date) to date-type string "2015-11-12 22:14:33" VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, parsing, datetime

I need to convert an oddly-formatted date string : `20151112 221433`
to the following format in visual basic: `2015-11-12 22:14:33`

I don't care if it's a `DateTime`, but I'd prefer to leave it as a string.

Comment: Rather than down voting, why doesn't someone just suggest that the question is not good for the site in some way so that I can delete, close, etc. ? Can't make improvements to the site if I don't know what's wrong with my question.

Comment: Agreed Rachael - One of my(very few) irritations is exactly that. I've tried rasing in in Meta, but nobody seems to like the idea.  Do Bang Head On Wall Loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string format is for sure the same.. including two digit month/day/second/etc.

than this should work:

```
Dim s As String = "20151112 221433"
s = s.Substring(0, 4) + "-" + s.Substring(5, 2) + "-" + s.Substring(6, 3) + s.Substring(9, 2) + ":" + s.Substring(11, 2) + ":" + s.Substring(13, 2)
```

Comment: oh my goodness. Thanks. Its one of those days. Have to laugh at myself here.

Comment: I don't blame you, it's ugly! but.. gets the job done.. ha.. slightly more elegant solution : Dim s As String = Long.Parse("20151112 221433".Replace(" ", "")).ToString("0000-00-00 00:00:00")

Comment: AHH! Long.Parse is what I was thinking of (but spent way more time than was practical on this micro-optimization). Thank you again. (Also funny username.)

Answer (score 4):

I would normally convert it first to date like this:

```
Dim sDate As String = "20151112 221433"

Dim _date As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, "yyyyMMdd HHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```